# modal is not displaying data separately

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to update my table using bootstrap dialog , but I when I retrieve my datatable from server side and embed php code into my modal to show the table data into the modal, and choose what the user wants to update in that form. it is showing the data from every row of my table into the modal , how can I fix it?

form_modal

```
<form id="product_update">
   <div class="row">
   <div class="form-group">
   <?php foreach ($product as $value): ?>
   <div class="col-xs-12">
      <label for="description">Name: </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description" title="product description" value="<?php echo $value['descripcion']; ?>" required>
      <div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
            <label for="cost_price">Cost Price:</label>
            <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
               <input type="text" class="form-control input-group-lg reg_name" id="cost_price" name="cost_price" title="cost_price"  placeholder="Last name" value="<?php echo $value['precio_compra']; ?>" required>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
            <label for="selling_price">Selling price: </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-group-lg reg_name" id="selling_price" name="selling_price" title="selling_price" placeholder="Last name" value="<?php echo $value['precio_venta']; ?>" required>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
            <label for="wprice">Wholeprice: </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="wprice" name="wprice" title="wprice" value="<?php echo $value['precio_mayoreo']; ?>" required>
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
            <label for="min_stock">Min stock: </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="min_stock" name="min_stock" title="min_stock" value="<?php echo $value['existencia_minima']; ?>" required>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
            <label for="stock">Stock: </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="stock" name="stock" title="stock" value="<?php echo $value['existencia']; ?>" required>
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
            <label for="max_stock">Max stock: </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="max_stock" name="max_stock" title="max_stock" value="<?php echo $value['existencia_maxima']; ?>" required>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
  <?php endforeach ?>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
            <label for="provider">Provider: </label>
            <select name="select-provider" id="select-provider">
                <option value="0">Select a provider</option>
                <?php foreach ($data as $value): ?>
                   <option value="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>"><?php echo $value['first_name'].' '.$value['last_name'] ?></option>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

modal js

```
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'a', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
    hash = data[0];
    $("#product_update").validate();
    BootstrapDialog.show({
        type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_WARNING,
        message: function(dialog) {
            var $message = $('<div></div>');
            var pageToLoad = dialog.getData('pageToLoad');
            $message.load(pageToLoad);

            return $message;
        },
        data: {
            'pageToLoad': URL_GET_VIEW_PRODUCT_UPDATE
        },
        closable: false,
        buttons: [{
            id: 'btn-ok',
            cssClass: 'btn-primary',
            icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-send',
            label: ' Save',
            action: function(e) {
                var description = $('#description').val();
                var description = $('#description').val();
                var cost_price = $('#cost_price').val();
                var selling_price = $('#selling_price').val();
                var wprice = $('#wprice').val();
                var min_stock = $('#min_stock').val();
                var stock = $('#stock').val();
                var max_stock = $('#max_stock').val();
                var provider_id = $('#select_provider').val();
                if ($("#product_update").valid()) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: URL_GET_UPDATE_PRODUCT,
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: { hash: hash, provider_id: provider_id, description: description, cost_price: cost_price,  selling_price: selling_price, wprice: wprice, min_stock: min_stock,   stock: stock, max_stock: max_stock },
                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log(data);
                            if (data.msg == 'successfully updated') {
                                $('#product_update')[0].reset();
                                table.ajax.reload();
                            } else if (data.min_stock == 'el stock no puede ser mayor al min') {
                                BootstrapDialog.show({
                                    type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DANGER,
                                    message: 'el stock no puede ser mayor al min'
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        },{
            id: 'btn-cancel',
            cssClass: 'btn-danger',
            icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            label: ' Cancel',
            action: function(e) {
                e.close();
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

model product

```
public function datatable(){
        $this->db->select('hash_id,codigo,descripcion,precio_compra,precio_venta,precio_mayoreo,existencia_minima,existencia,existencia_maxima,storelte_articulos.status');
        $this->db->from('storelte_articulos');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }
    public function isExistsProduct($data){
        $this->db->select('descripcion');
        $this->db->from('storelte_articulos');
        $this->db->where('descripcion',$data['descripcion']);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->num_rows() == 0 ? false : true;
    }

    public function addProduct($data){
        $query = 'UPDATE storelte_articulos SET hash_id = MD5(id) WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID()';
        $this->db->insert('storelte_articulos',$data);
        $this->db->query($query);
    }

    public function updateProduct($data) { 
        $this->db->where('md5(id)',$this->input->post('hash'));
        $this->db->update('storelte_articulos',$data); 
    }

     public function get_product() {
    $this->db->select('codigo,descripcion,precio_compra,precio_venta,precio_mayoreo,existencia_minima,existencia_maxima,existencia');
    $this->db->from('storelte_articulos');
    $this->db->where('md5(id)', $this->input->post('hash'));
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

modal img
[image: modal_img]

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your query is not targeting the single row that you intend to access.
If you are not querying on your table Primary/Unique Key, you should add `LIMIT 1` --but really you should be using the PK.

Also, you seem to be looping through all of the results from the query.

You'll need to post more of your code, because I can only make assumptions from what you've provided.

Why are you putting the Warning element at the top?

Where did you copy/paste your scripts from?

---

```
public function datatable(){
    $this->db->select('hash_id,codigo,descripcion,precio_compra,precio_venta,precio_mayoreo,existencia_minima,existencia,existencia_maxima,storelte_articulos.status');
```

> You will need some sort of `$this->db->where()` statement here that references the appropriate row id.

like:  `$this->db->where('id',$this->input->post('id'));`

```
    $this->db->from('storelte_articulos');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: I didnt copy / paste my scrips , they are from my own mind, I use warning element at the top because it is for update

Comment: @smithsmith See my update, you need at least a WHERE clause for your SELECT query.

Comment: @smithsmith  If my answer solves your issue, please award it the green tick so that this question is removed from the unresolved questions list.

Comment: it didnt work, but I was trying with get_where , and the same show everything

Comment: @smithsmith I don't think I am seeing all of the necessary codes.  From the main page, the ID must be passed to modal form.  Perhaps you could offer a pastebin link of your full main page, js, and your full modal code.  In later versions of bootstrap, the modal is meant to be a complete HTML file.  I will help you get this fixed.

Comment: @smithsmith Let's not let this question go stale.  Can I help you to get a resolution?  Is this general structure/method helpful for you? https://pastebin.com/CmFbZxVw

Comment: @smithsmith What is the status of this question?  All questions on SO deserve some kind of resolution.  If my answer doesn't correct the issue, please isolate the remaining problem so I can help you.

Answer (score -1):

```
$this->db->select('hash_id,codigo,descripcion,precio_compra,precio_venta,precio_mayoreo,existencia_minima,existencia,existencia_maxima,storelte_articulos.status');
```

You should add WHERE clause here. Basically you are selecting all rows if you don't add any kind of filtering in that clause. For example:

```
$this->db->select('hash_id,codigo,descripcion,precio_compra,precio_venta,precio_mayoreo,existencia_minima,existencia,existencia_maxima,storelte_articulos.status' WHERE hash_id='YOURHASHID')
```

Comment: this answer assumes too much PLUS you've essential duplicated my earlier posted answer.  There is no reason to believe that the `select()` function allows a where clause to be appended to the the string.  In fact, it would make no sense because there is a separate function that handles the from portion -- and that string would come between the SELECT and the WHERE.

Comment: how can I do it ? once I insert my item to the database , I update the hash_id column

Comment: @smithsmith basically you just want to display only one item, right? If yes, you need to update your code in order for you to display only the specific product you want. Can you show your db function?